# Fictitious Bejeweled blitz leaderboard characters

Tags: bejeweled-blitz

If you are not logged into Facebook, you initially have 3 fictitious characters (Zombie, Dr. Mojo, and Bjorn) who have scores for you to beat.  If you top them all that week, there is a new character with an even higher score added on for you to beat the next week.
How many new characters are added, what are their names, and in what order are they added?

I'm playing on iOS if that matters.

Answer (score 2):

- Zombie
- Dr. Mojo
- Bjorn
- Otis
- Teeny Phoenix
- Lex
- Zuma frog
- Walnut
- Cat tut
- Sunflowers
- Bubbles
- Pearl
- Splork
- Newspaper zombie
- Snackers
- Crazy Dave
- Jimmy lightening
- Mecha-anchovy
- Doom shroom
- Kahtiki Khan
- Blazing Steed
- Zombie Yeti
- Peashooter (900K)
- Disco Zombia (950K)
- Phoenix (1M)

I don't think anything is past the phoenix as it doesn't show anymore on the screen to unlock...

Answer (score 0):

Kolo Kamari is 850,000.  That's as far as I've got